# Communicating with different objects in LabVIEW Datasocket server with python

Tags: python, labview

I am trying to communicate with a LabVIEW datasocket server, which seems to be very different in structure to the python socket server than I have seen created. I want to be able to read/write certain objects, but not all. It seems that with my client code, it does connect to the server, but I am unable to read or write to it. It either is forced closed by the server if I am trying to read all data, or if I am trying to write to a specific object, python throws the error: struct.error: bad char in struct format or struct.error: required argument is not an integer if I use N or I in struct.unpack(). Any pointers would be helpful.

```
import socket
import json #converts data to byte streams
import select
import errno
import numpy
import struct 

def byteswap(i):
    return struct.unpack("!I", struct.pack("!I", i))[0]

HEADER_LENGTH = 200

IP = "localhost"
PORT = 3015 #6341 #8089 #3015
Engine_name = "ArrayTest"

# Create a socket
# socket.AF_INET - address family, IPv4, some otehr possible are AF_INET6, AF_BLUETOOTH, AF_UNIX
# socket.SOCK_STREAM - TCP, conection-based, socket.SOCK_DGRAM - UDP, connectionless, datagrams, socket.SOCK_RAW - raw IP packets
client_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

# Connect to a given ip and port
client_socket.connect((IP, PORT))

# Set connection to non-blocking state, so .recv() call won;t block, just return some exception we'll handle
client_socket.setblocking(True)

while True:
    arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
    send_data = byteswap(json.dumps({"test_data":arr}))
    print(send_data)
    client_socket.send(send_data.encode())
```

Comment: Whilst you can use raw TCP to connect to a data socket server, I am not sure the protocol is publicly available so it is difficult to know how to format messages that the server will understand and how to extract the information you require from responses. Whilst it might be possible to wrap the LabWindows C implementation for Python, implementing your own python to LabVIEW communication channel using TCP/IP is easier if you can modify your LabVIEW application.

Comment: That was one of the things that I considered, but the benefit for the datasocket server that Labview has built has a nice way of being able to access certain variables in the server. Similar to a database, but in RAM, which is highly desired for my use case. If I am not able to communicate with the built in server due to the protocol not being publicly available, I will start looking elsewhere and maybe do something with a pandas dataframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because Labview socket server has some unknown protocols, I ended up deciding to create my own server utilizing TCP through Labview and stripping the data using JSON. It is important to note that JSON is not used until Labview 2013 and Python is not introduced until Labview 2018. The server code that is roughly built is as below.

```
import socket 
import threading
import json

File_length = 4098 #maximum number of characters that can be passed back and forth. needs to be kept the same as labview
PORT = 3015
SERVER = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
ADDR = (SERVER, PORT)
FORMAT = 'utf-8'
DISCONNECT_MESSAGE = "!DISCONNECT"

server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server.bind(ADDR)

def handle_client(conn, addr):
    print(f"[NEW CONNECTION] {addr} connected.")

    Message_previous = ""

    connected = True
    while connected:
        Message = conn.recv(File_length).decode(FORMAT)
        Decoded_message = json.loads(Message)
        if Decoded_message != Message_previous:
            print(Decoded_message)
            Message_previous = Decoded_message

        String_arr = Decoded_message["Test Value Arr"]
        print(String_arr)
        print(String_arr[0])
        

def start():
    server.listen()
    print(f"[LISTENING] Server is listening on {SERVER}")
    while True:
        conn, addr = server.accept()
        thread = threading.Thread(target=handle_client, args=(conn, addr))
        thread.start()
        return threading.active_count()
        #print(f"[ACTIVE CONNECTIONS] {threading.active_count() - 1}")


print("[STARTING] server is starting...")
start()
```

I hope others find the rough setup helpful.